# Tensorflow Model fills up with NaNs during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am basically playing around with duplicating AlphaZero. It has worked for some small games, but I am trying to scale it up to work with a more complicated game. However, now my network after training on 2-10 million moves will just fill up with NaNs. Unfortunately, due to the fact that it isn't deterministic and the failure point occurs in such a wide range using the debugger has not been very effective. It takes about 5 minutes to train 12000 moves when I am having tfdbg check for "has_inf_or_nan". So the debugger is doing nothing for me because it would take a very long time to hit the error.

At the very bottom of this post, I'll describe what the model looks like.

Here is how I am using certain things that are common sources of NaNs:

Loss Functions (Single network with 2 outputs: policy (odds of selecting a move) and value (quality of the board position for the active player)):

Note: move_result_placeholder gets filled with a batch of moves that are the output of a MonteCarlo Tree Search. Since most of the move positions are invalid it is typically full of 0s with 5-10 that are floats that represent the odds of selecting that move. I have an assert that verifies they all sum to 1. When running training I also have asserts that verify none of the inputs are NaN. I select uniformly at random from a collection of the last 1,000,000 (Board State, Move, Reward) when populating the batch. Then I feed the board states, moves, and rewards into the training step.

```
self.loss_policy = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(self.move_result_placeholder, out_dense)
self.loss_value = 
    tf.losses.mean_squared_error(self.value_result_placeholder, 
    tf.reshape(self.out_value_layer, shape=[-1,]))
self.total_loss = self.loss_policy + self.loss_value
```

Optimizer (learning rate 1e-4):

```
self.train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate_placeholder).minimize(self.total_loss, name="optimizer")
```

Softmax:

```
self.out_policy_layer = tf.nn.softmax(out_dense, name="out_policy_layer")
```

Batch Normalization (is_training is a placeholder that is 1 when training and 0 when playing games) batch_norm_decay is .999:

```
input_bn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(input_conv, center=True, scale=True, is_training=self.is_training, decay=self._config.batch_norm_decay)
```

Regularization (L2 on all weights in layers scale is 1e-4):

```
initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
if use_regularizer:
        regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=self._config.l2_regularizer_scale)

    weights = tf.get_variable(name, shape=shape, initializer=initializer, regularizer=regularizer)
```

MODEL DESCRIPTION:

The model is created in tensorflow and consists of an input layer that is 4x8x3 (batch size 1024). This captures the state of the 4x8 board and how many moves have been made since a player has scored and how many times that board state has been seen during that specific game. That feeds into a conv2d layer with kernel size of 3x3 and strides=1. I then apply BatchNormalization `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(input_conv, center=True, scale=True, is_training=self.is_training, decay=self._config.batch_norm_decay)` and relu. At the end of the input relu the size is 4x8x64.

After that there are 5 residual blocks. After the residual block it splits into two. The first is the policy network output which runs it through another convolutional layer with kernal size of 1x1 with strides of 1 and a batch normalization and a ReLU. At this point it is 4x8x2 and it gets flattened and run through a dense layer and then to a softmax to output 256 outputs that represent the odds that it will pick any given move. The 256 outputs map to the 4x8 board with planes for the direction the piece is moving. So the first 4x8 would tell you the odds of selecting a piece and moving it Northwest. The second would tell you the odds of selecting a piece and moving it Northeast, etc.

On the other side of the split is the value output. On that side it runs through a convolutional layer then it gets flattened and goes through a dense layer and finally through a TanH so it outputs a single value that tells us the quality of that board state.

Weights for all of the layers are using L2 Regularization (1e-4).

Loss is Cross Entropy for the policy side and Mean Squared Error for the value side, and I am using the Adam Optimizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually a video card that was dying. If you are running into a similar problem, and you investigate the usual sources without success remember to consider an issue with the memory in your videocard.

Comment: this is not really a solution, just a list of things you tried. please only mark answers that are generally applicable or address the issue specifically

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would investigate the tensorflow debugger plugin for tensorboard. You will find that using this tool, it is very easy to trace problems through your graph.

You can step through computations in your graph, and you can also track the occurrence of NaN values that pop up.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard/plugins/debugger

Answer (score 1):

Well this is just too broad a problem to tackle like this. In general, you need to think about what can produce `NaN`s and approach this issue with modular disabling, that is disable or bypass things in your model and see if the error disappears. Some candidates where problems might originate: batch normalization, or softmax for some edge cases (all zero input), or you might have a gradient explosion (try to limit learning rate.)

So for example, turn off batch normalization and run the model, see if the error happens. If yes, lower the learning rate a few orders of magnitude. And so on.

Comment: Yeah I have been trying various things, and I haven't been able to figure out. That is why I made a post as detailed as possible. Blind hope that someone would read it and point out something stupid I was doing.  I'm at a loss. I haven't actually tried disabling batch norm yet so I'll give that a shot. Thanks!